# Why is it possible to calculate the maximum error of a Taylor-polynomial with the Lagrange-remainder formula?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

We can calculate the maximum error of a Taylor-polynomial of n order with the following formula:

$$ R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)(x-c)^{(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}, $$

I know how to use this formula but I'm trying to understand more how everything works under the hood.

More specifically, why can we use the next n+1 term of a n-Taylor polynomial with a derivative value of $\xi$ to get the maximum error?

Comment: You may find useful the *exact* form of the remainder ([proven](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1287198) using integration by parts): $$R_n(x):=f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{n}f^{(k)}(c)\frac{(x-c)^k}{k!}\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{n!}\int_c^x(x-y)^n f^{(n+1)}(y)\,dy}.$$

Comment: See math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1516/math1010c/Taylor.pdf